# Why is my mac so slow? - No programs open but "app memory" high

Tags: macos, memory, debug, osx-el-capitan, memory-leaks

I simply can't figure out why my Mac is running so slow. Here's what I've tried:

- Closing applications (including Firefox and Chrome)
- Shutting down my computer
- Entering "sudo purge" in the terminal
- Deleting recently installed applications

Is it the "saveapi" or "kernel_task" processes? How can I figure out what's going on there?

Here is a link to the activity monitor results

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have 8GB, less than 50% is in use. Is it slow all the time? Do you have AV or backups running? You should take a look at the CPU usage rather than memory.

Comment: @Burgi What is AV? I don't have any backups running. The slowness has started over the past couple of days where I've had a lot of chrome/firefox windwos open and also running various machine learning scripts in ipython notebooks.

Comment: AV stands for Antivirus

Comment: @Burgi - I had Avira Anti-virus running at the time of the screanshots. When I disabled it, the results didn't change much. Also, it's not something which was installed recently.

Comment: Do you have an SSD? What you're showing in the Activity Monitor looks pretty normal to me.

Comment: Yes,  I have an SSD. Wouldn't that make things faster?

Comment: @dshlachter if the activity monitor is normal why does the "memory used " say. 3gb but the sum total of all the activities listed seem to add up to a little more than 1gb?